# Making assumptions about type parameters?

Tags: java, generics

I want to subclass Iterator into what I'll call FooIterator. My code looks something like this:

```
public class FooIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
  public FooIterator(Collection<Bar> bars) {
    innerIterator = bars.iterator();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return innerIterator.hasNext();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public E next() {
    Bar bar = innerIterator.next();
    return new E(bar);
  }

  @Override
  public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Don't remove from FooIterator!");
  }

  private Iterator<Bar> innerIterator;
}
```

...except, of course, this doesn't work because I can't instantiate a new E from a Bar.

I would only ever use this with an E that has a constructor that takes a Bar. Is there any way to "prove" that to the compiler, or to just throw a runtime error if E doesn't have an appropriate constructor?

Or perhaps I'm just not using the right design pattern here? I've been doing a lot of C++ recently, and I feel like I might be approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: You could do it with reflection, but that'd be rather ugly, and all the checks would be at runtime.

Comment: `E` could be anything, but you want to instantiate a new `E` passing its constructor a `Bar`.  Why?  It would be much more helpful is you explained your ultimate goal.  It's not clear from the example what you intend, but I really doubt this is the way to do it in Java.

Comment: It is impossible to create a new E due to type erasure. The type information exists only at compile time, not at runtime, so the VM could not possibly construct a new E no matter what you could 'prove'. This is very different from C++ templates, if you are working with that mindset.

Comment: I feel like if you're using generics, you ought to be able to make it not make any assumptions on the types that you'll use it with (especially with type erasure). You might actually want a different paradigm altogether, but we need to know your use case to be sure.

Comment: My use case is pretty much what it looks like: I have a collection of Bars, I need to get a bunch of Es (preferably iterator, but obviously collection is also fine). E is going to be one of many possible classes (generated code).

Comment: @wolfcastle: Yeah, I'm pretty used to C++ templates. I'm definitely open to the idea that I'm forcing something here, because this doesn't feel like proper Java design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a somewhat convoluted approach but it could work and would be type safe (solutions using reflection won't). It basically consists in delegating the construction of an `E` from a `Bar` to a separate class. You could have a `BarConverter` interface:

```java
interface BarConverter<E> {
    E convert (Bar bar);
}
```

Then your class could become:

```java
public class FooIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

    public FooIterator(Collection<Bar> bars, BarConverter<E> converter) {
        innerIterator = bars.iterator();
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        Bar bar = innerIterator.next();
        return converter(bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution, and it happens to work particularly well for me because I might want to change the contents of the convert function over time. Thanks! I never thought flexible templates would be the C++ feature I'd miss the most...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to instantiate a type parameter like that.

A workaround is to pass the `Class<E>` type parameter in the constructor, along with the `Collection<Bar>`:

```
private Class<E> clazz;

public FooIterator(Collection<Bar> bars, Class<E> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
    innerIterator = bars.iterator();
}
```

And then in `next()` method, you can make use of reflection to create instance of `E`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public E next() {
    Bar bar = innerIterator.next();

    E instance = null;
    try {
        instance = clazz.getConstructor(Bar.class).newInstance(bar);

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (instance == null) {
        // throw an unchecked exception    
    }

    return instance;
}
```

**P.S:** You should in general do a better exception handling, than I've used here. I've just catched all the exception in `Exception` for brevity. In practice, you should have catch block for each specific exception.

Also, rather than using `e.printStackTrace()`, you can log some helpful message.

While instantiating `FooIterator`, you need to pass an extra argument - the class for which you are creating the iterator.

Comment: This approach is good, but you've committed some "atrocities" in the implementation.  Catching `Exception` is bad.  Printing random stacktraces is bad.  Returning `null` in the event of an error is bad.  You should NOT do this kind of thing in example code ... 'cos copy-and-paste programmers are likely to copy you.

Comment: @StephenC. Well, I should have quoted that, I've just used those stuffs for brevity. Will add them though.

Comment: @StephenC. Although, your first 2 points is absolutely fine, which I understand. 3rd point also I understand, that it should not be done, but I guess, there is no other way than returning a `null`, in this case. As `E` is a type parameter.

Comment: My (3rd) point is that if `next()` can't create the instance, it should throw an unchecked exception or let the existing one propagate.  Turning errors into nulls creates "opportunities" for more errors (i.e. NPEs), while obscuring the cause of the original error.

Answer (score 0):

This feels a bit hacky, but with an interface and a method which simply constructs itself, you could do this:

```
interface Barable
{
    Barable construct(Barable bar);
}

class Bar implements Barable
{
    Bar(Barable bar)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public Barable construct(Barable bar)
    {
        return new Bar(bar);
    }
}

class FooIterator<E extends Barable> implements Iterator<E>
{
    public FooIterator(Collection<Bar> bars)
    {
        innerIterator = bars.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return innerIterator.hasNext();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public E next()
    {
        Bar bar = innerIterator.next();
        return (E) bar.construct(bar);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Don't remove from FooIterator!");
    }
    private Iterator<Bar> innerIterator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to parameterize `Bar` and add a method to it to create a new `E`.  Something like this:

```
class Bar<E> {

    // ... more implementation ...

    public E build() {
        // create your `E` object here
    }

}
```

and then your code would do something like this:

```
public class FooIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

    public FooIterator(Collection<Bar<E>> bars) {
        innerIterator = bars.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return innerIterator.hasNext();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public E next() {
        Bar<E> bar = innerIterator.next();
        return bar.build();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Don't remove from FooIterator!");
    }

    private Iterator<Bar<E>> innerIterator;
}
```

Comment: Note that as it is, `build` could only type-safely return `null`.

Comment: @PaulBellora I can't see how null would be the only possible type-safe value, could you explain that?

Comment: `E` is a type parameter, which is erased at runtime, so without a `Class<E>` or a prefabbed `E` instance, there's no way for `build` to have one to return.

Comment: Yes, but `Bar` type is parameterized and "is aware" of `E`, it is up to the implementor how to build an `E`. You don't need a `Class<E>` as parameter of `build`, it could be elsewhere inside `Bar`s implementation (or even not to be present at all, it depends on the strategy chosen to build an `E`)